# Laravel Accessor setting numbers times 100 on set and divide on get

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I want to store shipping costs in my database as Integers and Doubles are giving.
So on Get I will divide the value by 100 and when Set I do the values times 100.

But why is this not working?

```
protected function shippingcosts(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value, $attributes) => [
            'Small' => is_numeric($attributes['Small']) ? ($attributes['Small'] / 100) : 0,
            'Large' => is_numeric($attributes['Large']) ? ($attributes['Large'] / 100) : 0,
            'BulkSizeForLarge' => $attributes['BulkSizeForLarge'],
        ],
        set: fn ($value) => [
            'Small' => is_numeric($value['Small']) ? ($value['Small'] * 100) : 0,
            'Large' => is_numeric($value['Large']) ? ($value['Large'] * 100) : 0,
            'BulkSizeForLarge' => $value['BulkSizeForLarge'],
        ],
    );
}
```

In my Model it is stored in a JSON column in the database and casting is set to:

```
  protected $casts = [
        'shippingcosts' => 'collection',
    ];
```

As far as I'm concerned when reading the Laravel docs this should work, but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you getting back? do you have any errors? Is it not being stored as expected? Did you try `'shippingcosts' => 'array',` instead of `'shippingcosts' => 'collection',` just to see if something changes?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, without any results

Comment: which version of laravel you are using ? This syntax only works on above laravel 9.x

Comment: @user1469734 if you want to get help, you need to add more details, what are you having returned on the code? What is it being stored on the database?

Comment: @BholaKr.Khawas I use it with Laravel 9. Other Attribute castings are working just fine.

Comment: Please share any error that you are getting/ the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function shippingcosts(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value, $attributes) => [
                'Small' => is_numeric($value['Small']) ? ($value['Small'] / 100) : 0,
                'Large' => is_numeric($value['Large']) ? ($value['Large'] / 100) : 0,
                'BulkSizeForLarge' => $value['BulkSizeForLarge'],
            ],
            set: fn ($value) => [
                'Small' => is_numeric($value['Small']) ? ($value['Small'] * 100) : 0,
                'Large' => is_numeric($value['Large']) ? ($value['Large'] * 100) : 0,
                'BulkSizeForLarge' => $value['BulkSizeForLarge'],
            ],
    );
}
```

Use `$value` instead of `$attribute`,